# How to optimise a SQL query to check for consistency of column values across tables

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I would like to check across multiple tables that the same keys / same number of keys are present in each of the tables.

Currently I have created a solution that checks the count of keys per individual table, checks the count of keys when all tables are merged together, then compares.

This solution works but I wonder if there is a more optimal solution...

Example solution as it stands:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT variable) AS num_ids FROM table_a;

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT variable) AS num_ids FROM table_b;

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT variable) AS num_ids FROM table_c;

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.variable) AS num_ids
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT VARIABLE FROM table_a) a
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT VARIABLE FROM table_b) b ON a.variable = b.variable
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT VARIABLE FROM table_c) c ON a.variable = c.variable;
```

UPDATE:

The difficultly that I'm facing putting this together in one query is that any of the tables might not be unique on the VARIABLE that I am looking to check, so I've had to use distinct before merging to avoid expanding the join

Comment: If table `A` has `1, 2, 2, 3` and table `B` has `1, 1, 2, 3`, are they considered to be the same or different?

Comment: In the situation you mention I want them to be considered the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we are only counting, I think there is no need in joining the tables on the `variable` column. A `UNION` should be enough.
We still have to use `DISTINCT` to ignore/suppress duplicates, which often means extra sort.
An index on `variable` should help for getting counts for separate tables, but it will not help for getting the count of the combined table.

Here is an example for comparing two tables:

```
WITH
CTE_A
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT variable) AS CountA
    FROM TableA
)
,CTE_B
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT variable) AS CountB
    FROM TableB
)
,CTE_AB
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT variable) AS CountAB
    FROM
    (
        SELECT variable
        FROM TableA

        UNION ALL 
        -- sic! use ALL here to avoid sort when merging two tables
        -- there should be only one distinct sort for the outer `COUNT`

        SELECT variable
        FROM TableB
    ) AS AB
)
SELECT
    CASE WHEN CountA = CountAB AND CountB = CountAB 
    THEN 'same' ELSE 'different' END AS ResultAB
FROM
    CTE_A
    CROSS JOIN CTE_B
    CROSS JOIN CTE_AB
;
```

Three tables:

```
WITH
CTE_A
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT variable) AS CountA
    FROM TableA
)
,CTE_B
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT variable) AS CountB
    FROM TableB
)
,CTE_C
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT variable) AS CountC
    FROM TableC
)
,CTE_ABC
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT variable) AS CountABC
    FROM
    (
        SELECT variable
        FROM TableA

        UNION ALL 
        -- sic! use ALL here to avoid sort when merging two tables
        -- there should be only one distinct sort for the outer `COUNT`

        SELECT variable
        FROM TableB

        UNION ALL 
        -- sic! use ALL here to avoid sort when merging two tables
        -- there should be only one distinct sort for the outer `COUNT`

        SELECT variable
        FROM TableC
    ) AS AB
)
SELECT
    CASE WHEN CountA = CountABC AND CountB = CountABC AND CountC = CountABC 
    THEN 'same' ELSE 'different' END AS ResultABC
FROM
    CTE_A
    CROSS JOIN CTE_B
    CROSS JOIN CTE_C
    CROSS JOIN CTE_ABC
;
```

I deliberately chose `CTE`, because as far as I know Postgres materializes `CTE` and in our case each `CTE` will have only one row.

---

Using [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) **with order by** is even better variant, if it is available on redshift. You'll still need to use `DISTINCT`, but you don't have to merge all tables together.

```
WITH
CTE_A
AS
(
    SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT variable ORDER BY variable) AS A
    FROM TableA
)
,CTE_B
AS
(
    SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT variable ORDER BY variable) AS B
    FROM TableB
)
,CTE_C
AS
(
    SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT variable ORDER BY variable) AS C
    FROM TableC
)
SELECT
    CASE WHEN A = B AND B = C
    THEN 'same' ELSE 'different' END AS ResultABC
FROM
    CTE_A
    CROSS JOIN CTE_B
    CROSS JOIN CTE_C
;
```

Comment: thanks for this, the array_agg isn't available in postgre version of redshift, but even still the second solution you provided is more efficient than the approach I had.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is probably the nastiest piece of SQL I could build for you :) I will forever deny that I wrote this and that my stackoverflow account was hacked ;)

```
SELECT
  'All OK'
WHERE
  ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM table_a ) = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM table_b )
  AND ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM table_b ) = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM table_c )
```

By the way, this won't optimise the query - it's still doing three queries (but I guess it's better than 4?).

UPDATE: In light of your use-case below: NEW sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a0403/1

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  tbl_a.a_count,
  tbl_b.b_count,
  tbl_c.c_count
FROM
  ( SELECT COUNT(id) a_count, array_agg(id order by id) ids FROM table_a) tbl_a,
  ( SELECT COUNT(id) b_count, array_agg(id order by id) ids FROM table_b) tbl_b,
  ( SELECT COUNT(id) c_count, array_agg(id order by id) ids FROM table_c) tbl_c
WHERE
  tbl_a.ids = tbl_b.ids
  AND tbl_b.ids = tbl_c.ids
```

The above query will only return if all tables have the same number of rows, ensuring that the IDS are also the same.

Comment: thanks for your reply...and don't worry I wont mention it to anyone :) Only problem with the solution you suggested is that although unlikely it wouldn't catch if there were the same number, but different ids across tables (for example: table_a ids 1,2,3 and table_b ids 1,2,4

Comment: Only having a chance to look back at this now, thanks for your update, I believe though that this still wont cover the case where the number of ids match, but the ids themselves are different (i.e. 1,2,3 => 3 numbers, 1,2,4 => 3 numbers, but the two sets are different) - please correct me if I'm missing something?